# Optimize RequireJS modules containing JSP tags

Tags: jsp, optimization, requirejs, cdn

We have a large legacy site that we want to migrate to a Single-Page Application:
 - RequireJS models
 - Backbone views, models, router/Underscore/Underscore templates/RESTful API Single-Page Application (end of buzz words).

Our legacy site has the following features:

- a Java backend with managers/DAOs
- JSP templates
- CDN for fetching images and scripts

Our legacy site uses JSP templates, and we have a couple of issues concerning that:

- We use a JSP tag to insert translated texts from Java resource bundles (properties files)
- We use a JSP tag to insert CDN image URLs with:

  - a randomized CDN hostname
  - a version number unique for that particular image (could be changed to build/release number)

We really want to use the CDN for serving JavaScript modules, Underscore templates and images. We also really want to use the RequireJS optimizer so the clients don't flood our servers with requests, but the optimizer fails when it tries to parse JSP tags:

Unexpected token <

So we want to get rid of all i18n/CDN JSP tags in our JavaScript modules and Underscore templates.

I think we can solve the i18n issue with RequireJS i18n functionality, or writing our own Javascript i18n solution, but I would love some input if there's some best practice.

The CDN issue is a bit trickier, we would like to keep the hostname and version functionality. We can probably write a JavaScript solution for that as well, but it would be a bit messy. Does anyone have a great solution for this? :-D

Cheers!